# Preprocess a Tensorflow tensor in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have set up a CNN in Tensorflow where I read my data with a TFRecordReader. It works well but I would like to do some more preprocessing and data augmentation than offered by the `tf.image` functions. I would specifically like to do some randomized scaling.

Is it possible to process a Tensorflow tensor in Numpy? Or do I need to drop the TFRecordReader and rather do all my preprocessing in Numpy and feed data using the feed_dict? I suspect that the feed_dict method is slow when training on images, but I might be wrong?

Comment: `feed_dict` and `py_func` copy the data between TF and Python runtime using single-threaded `memcpy`, so you may getting 2GB/s transfer rates which should not be a bottleneck for dataset like ImageNet. The slowness is more likely to happen in the custom preprocessing stage

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you could create a custom I/O pipeline that fetches intermediate results back from TensorFlow using one or more threads, applies arbitrary Python logic, and then feeds them into a queue for subsequent processing. The resulting program would be somewhat more complicated, but I suggest you look at the [threading and queues HOWTO](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html) for information on how to get started.

---

There is an **experimental** feature that might make this easier, if you [install from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources).

If you have already built a preprocessing pipeline using TensorFlow ops, the easiest way to add some custom Python code is to use the [`tf.py_func()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/script_ops.html#py_func) operator, which takes a list of `Tensor` objects, and a Python function that maps one or more NumPy arrays to one or more NumPy arrays.

For example, let's say you have a pipeline like this:

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader(...)
image_t = tf.image.decode_png(tf.parse_single_example(reader.read(), ...))
```

...you could use `tf.py_func()` to apply some custom NumPy processing as follows:

```
from scipy import ndimage
def preprocess(array):
  # `array` is a NumPy array containing.
  return ndimage.rotate(array, 45)

image_t = tf.py_func(preprocess, [image_t], [tf.float32])
```

Comment: Thanks! Just for other readers: to be able to do further processing, for example through `tf.train.shuffle_batch`, I had to reshape the results of `tf.py_func`, which makes sense.

Comment: Hmm, now I'm having some trouble extracting the results of the function. I call it like `n1, n2, n3 = tf.py_func(get_triplet, [orig_tensor, truth_tensor], [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32])`, and I've checked that it enters the function, and it returns 3 float32 NumPy arrays, however I get the error `tensorflow/python/lib/core/py_func.cc:299] Unimplemented: Unsupported numpy type 17` before the `tf.py_func` finishes. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I think I figured it out, I needed to return `[n1, n2, n3]` from my Python function.

Comment: @mrry does py_func get executed multithreaded if there are more than one thread working for the queue? Given Python has a global interpreter lock

Comment: @MinLin If there are multiple `py_func()` operations in the graph, they may be dispatched concurrently by different TensorFlow threads, but each thread will acquire the GIL before calling into Python. If you call an API that releases the GIL ([such as NumPy](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ParallelProgramming.html)), you may still get a parallel speedup in this situation.