# Print full value of tensor into console or write to file in tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I need to print a large tensor ([32,32,3]) into the console, and I only get output like this:

```
[[[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
..., 
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]]

[[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
..., 
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]]

[[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
..., 
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]]

..., 
[[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
..., 
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]]

[[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
..., 
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]]

[[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
..., 
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]
[245 245 245]]]
```

How can I get tensorflow to print out the entire tensor, instead of truncating it with the ellipses?

Comment: Use py_func as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34951694/419116

Answer (score 3):

The value returned from a TensorFlow [`Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) call is a NumPy ndarray, so this rendering is controlled by NumPy itself. One simple way to ensure that all elements are printed is to use [`numpy.set_printoptions()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
import numpy
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)
```

Comment: Actually in current versions this gives an error, `numpy.inf` will work better

Answer (score 2):

use [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt):

```
x = y = z = np.arange(0.0,5.0,1.0)
np.savetxt('test.out', x, delimiter=',')   # X is an array
np.savetxt('test.out', (x,y,z))   # x,y,z equal sized 1D arrays
np.savetxt('test.out', x, fmt='%1.4e')   # use exponential notation
```