# How to print full (not truncated) tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

Whenever I try printing I always get truncated results

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)

tensor = tf.constant(np.ones(999))

tensor = tf.Print(tensor, [tensor])

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tensor)
```

As you can see I've followed a guide I found on [Print full value of tensor into console or write to file in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298299/print-full-value-of-tensor-into-console-or-write-to-file-in-tensorflow)

But the output is simply

...\core\kernels\logging_ops.cc:79] [1 1 1...]

I want to see the full tensor, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

This is solved easily by checking [the Tensorflow API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) for `tf.Print`. Pass `summarize=n` where `n` is the number of elements you want displayed.

Comment: To print the whole tensor, simply set the parameter to the size of the tensor, which can be done using tf.size.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/size

Comment: This has since been deprecated in favour of tf.print (lowercase p) https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print

Comment: You can now use `summarize=-1` to print entire tensor, rather than `tf.size`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print#args

Comment: Cool! This answer is rather outdated anyway since it's for TF 1.x and the new `tf.print` is much easier to use.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it as follows in TensorFlow 2.x:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.constant(np.ones(999))
tf.print(tensor, summarize=-1)
```

From TensorFlow docs -> summarize: The first and last summarize elements within each dimension are recursively printed per Tensor. If set to -1, it will print all elements of every tensor.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print

Answer (score 1):

To print all tensors without truncation in TensorFlow 2.x:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
```